# Is Interrupt functionality is availabe in Kubernetes minikube autoscaling?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, autoscaling, hpa

I have used custom metrics API and have successfully auto scaled the service based on some metrics.But here is the point the auto scaling works in way that the minikube's HPA(horizontal pod autoscaler) will check the particular URL/API and try to find out the metric value repetitively with some polling period.For example HPA will check for the value for every 15 seconds.So this is continuous polling from HPA to the URL/API to fetch the value of that metric.After that it will simply compare the value with the target reference value given and try to scale.

What I want is, the API/URL should trigger the minikube HPA whenever needed, it's like HPA should work as a interrupt here in simple words.

call for autoscale should be from Service/API to HPA not from HPA to Service !

is this feature available in Kubernetes ? or do you have any comments in this scenario ? please share your view on this I am currently in last stage and this question is stopping my progress!

Comment: Hi @Museb Momin, "HPA should act as interrupting." The question is: when should this interruption occur? There must be a mechanism to count the metrics. This is how the minikube autoscaler works. You can also create a Custom Pod Autoscaler. Here is the complete tutorial: https://custom-pod-autoscaler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
However, you will not avoid collecting metrics:  https://custom-pod-autoscaler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/metric-gathering/

Please let me know if the solution helped

Comment: thanks @MikołajGłodziak for your view ... I have gone through the links and tried implementing the custom pod autoscaler but looks like lot of things are deprecated and not having latest version.when I ran the cpa.yaml file it gave me this error (no matches for kind CustomPodAutoscaler in version custompodautoscaler.com/v1).

Comment: I don't think such native k8s solution exists, but maybe you are interested with [Kubernetes-based Event Driven Autoscaler](https://keda.sh/).  I found also a good  [tutorial](https://itnext.io/keda-kubernetes-based-event-driven-autoscaling-48491c79ec74) to KEDA. KEDA handles the triggers to respond to events that happen in other services and scales workloads as needed. It should help you.